# Are groovy variables null-initialized, or is this an IntelliJ bug?

Tags: groovy

IntelliJ highlights the 'foo' variable in gray, and says "assignment is not used". What I want to know is - it is right or not...

If this were java and not groovy, I know it wouldn't be right.

```
public class Foo
{
  public Foo()
  {
    Foo foo = null; // this 'foo' instance is gray ("assignment not used")
    try
    {
      foo = new Foo()
      // ...
    }
    finally
    {
      if (foo != null)
        foo.release();
    }

  }

  public void release(){}
}
```

Comment: You set a local veriable `foo` to `null` then immediately set it to `new Foo()`...  I'd agree with IntelliJ

Comment: @tim_yates - you would be wrong. If Foo's constructor throws an exception, then foo is never initialized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Groovy (and Java) local variables must be explicitly initialized before use. [Java Language Specification: Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value
>   before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment
>   (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite
>   assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

Comment: This does not apply to stack/local variables. Trying reading a local variable without initializing it first, and you're in for a compilation error.

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are correct.  Java requires [Definite Assignment](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/defAssign.html) to be proved by the compiler.  I can't find any reference to this in the groovy spec. However, examining some local variable declarations with the groovyConsole AST browser confirms that groovy implicitly assigns null to local variables.

Comment: Cool, so this is in fact not a bug in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 5):

It is a bug. I've created an issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-81188